# is there a way to type a type utility in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a few functions which do runtime and *type* checks for whether a given variable is of a particular type. For context, here's an example:

```
export type IsBoolean<T> = T extends boolean ? true : false;

export function isBoolean<T extends any>(i: T) {
  return (typeof i === "boolean") as IsBoolean<T>;
}
```

So my real question is ... how does one *type* a utility type like `IsBoolean<T>`? Being able to express this as a generalized type could be a powerful abstraction. I'm imagining something like:

```
export Validator<T, U> = 
    U<T> extends true 
        ? true 
        : U<T> extends false 
            ? false 
            : never;
```

This syntax *does not* work but is there a means to do this?

---

Addition:

The example above used a type check for Boolean, and like Boolean types most of the "wide" types use effectively the same sort of type utility:

```
type IsBoolean<T> = T extends boolean ? true : false;
type IsString<T> = T extends string ? true : false;
```

However, the pattern changes for other types such as for `true` or even a base `Function`:

```
// there are three states: true, false, and unknown
type IsTrue<T> = IsBoolean<T> extends true
  ? // is a boolean
    T extends true
    ? true
    : T extends false
    ? false
    : unknown
  : // not a boolean
    false;

// runtime checks such as `X typeof ==="function"` test for both
// the simple function constructor as well as functions which have
// props but that means the type pattern for any function is:
type FunctionType = Function | (Function & {[key:string]:any})
type IsFunction<T> = T extends FunctionType
```

In the latter example, the introduction of `FunctionType` allows us to move the base function example back into the first general pattern but with functions which have props you'll likely want strong typing on the props too (for a full validation anyway). This will move you away again from the general pattern.

There are many other examples of where a validator (which checks for type in both types and runtime) can be expressed as a type utility (aka, a type with a generic) but no single utility can do the trick.

This then leads to the heart of the question ... can we simply express a type as being a *type utility* so that multiple patterns can be injected into the generalized type?

Comment: What do you plan to pass into `Validator`... something like `Validator<T, IsBoolean>` presumably? If so, no there is no direct way to do this without higher kinded types as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  (`IsBoolean` is not a first-class "thing" in TypeScript.  It's a type function, but you can't refer to type functions in the abstract.)  You could simulate higher kinded types with a bunch of boilerplate and annoyance, but nothing that would just work right out of the box.

Comment: yes that's right @jcalz

Comment: You could type this abstraction, you are just using the wrong tools. You could try doing something like `type Validator<T> = (object: unknown) => object is T` and then use it like `const isBoolean: Validator<boolean> = (object) => typeof object ==='boolean'`. You can type pretty much any validator like this, it's just that you need to change the way you think about them a bit, like using type guards instead of generics (like `IsBoolean`) everywhere

Comment: @AlexChashin That is a type guard and that works fine but fits a different use case. I am using type guards already and they work fine. This might be more apparent when you look at type literals like `true` instead of wider types like `boolean`. What is needed is a type utility to be applied and with wide types its typically just a simple _X extends Y_ operator.

Comment: @AlexChashin I have updated the question to better describe what I'm talking about

Comment: Ultimately I think @jcalz has naiiled down the problem I'm trying to solve ... not sure I have my head wrapped around the "work around" being proposed in that link but I'm going to try and understand it now.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite get the problem you are trying to solve :) I could think more about your problem if you provided actual runtime code where you would like to apply this `Validator` abstraction, because when you are only writing types, I don't quite get why you would need `Validator<T, IsBoolean>` when you can just write `IsBoolean<T>`. Or are you trying to type the types? Looks a bit weird

Comment: no problem; if you can't see the utility, I'm not going to try to talk you into it.